# User Control Not Fit into row

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have created my custom user control in C# which has combo box and a panel.When I put that user control into a row (cell) of a

```
System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
```

only a combo box is shown and a panel is not shown. I know it is because height of cell is less than the height of my custom user control. My question is that can I make my custom user control shrink and grow according to the container that it was placed in because I also wanted my panel to be shown and not only the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171688%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

To align and stretch a control

1. Drag a TableLayoutPanel control from the Toolbox onto your form.
2. Drag a Button control from the Toolbox into the upper-left cell of
   the TableLayoutPanel control. The Button control is centered in the
   cell.
3. Set the value of the Button control's Anchor property to
   Left,Right. The Button control stretches to match the width of the
   cell.
4. Set the value of the Button control's Anchor property to
   Top,Bottom. The Button control stretches to match the height of the
   cell.
5. Set the value of the Button control's Dock property to Fill.
   The Button control expands to fill the cell.
6. Set the value of the
   Button control's Dock property to None. The Button control returns
   to its original size and moves to the upper-left corner of the cell.
   The Windows Forms Designer has set the Anchor property to Top, Left.
7. Set the value of the Button control's Anchor property to
   Bottom,Right. The Button control moves to the lower-right corner of
   the cell.
8. Set the value of the Button control's Anchor property to
   None. The Button control moves to the center of the cell.

Comment: I have already tried that method. I think you got wrong assumption of the question. By custom user control , I do not mean a "Button" from a Toolbox but non-standard custom control which is composed of combo box and a panel (created by myself). What I mean is that assume my user control has a height of "100" and the height of cell in TableLayoutPanel only has a height of "50" therefore cannot fully display my custom control.Therefore I am asking if there is a way to dynamically shrink my custom control (combo box+ panel size) according to the container it was placed in.

Comment: Lopht, I do understand your question.  Your control should be no different than a button control.  Since I cannot see your control code, what I assume is happening is your panel is fixed size.  What you need to do is anchor your panel (if that is what you want to scale) to your control boundary.  If you want the scale of the combobox to change, that cannot be done easily in winforms.  But you can scale with width and height properties with the anchor.

Comment: If your goal is to "zoom" the control. that is hard to do in winforms.